# Joomla - Add Get Variables to Menu Item Link

Tags: joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I made a custom component and I'm trying to make the menu item link add &id=x, however I can't seem to find any documentation on how to make this work. The field is read only, but even then I would still want it to be automated (similar to how adding an article works). It will be taking a value from a parameter field. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in this thread towards the bottom.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2250321

It's also important to note that the params to be added to the link need to be out of the params, like so.

```
<state>
    <name>Standard Page Layout</name>
    <url>
        <param name="id" type="text" default="0" label="Page ID" description="The ID of the page to view." />
    </url>
    <params>
    </params>
</state>
```

The following is incorrect.

```
<state>
    <name>Standard Page Layout</name>
    <params>
    <url>
        <param name="id" type="text" default="0" label="Page ID" description="The ID of the page to view." />
    </url>
    </params>
</state>
```